# How to use Webpack for Bootstrap?

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am using webpack to bundle some boostrap and other css files into one, the following is the **webpack.config.js** file
var htmlWebPack = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/main.ts",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {   
    extensions: ['.js','.ts']
  },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
          },
          {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      {
             test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
           loader: 'url-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
    new htmlWebPack({
        template: './index.html',

    }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("minified-style.css"),
    ]

};
```

and i have referenced my bootstrap folder in the main.ts file like this

```
require('../Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css');
require('../Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
```

but when i run webpack, i am getting the error something like this

> D:\project\angularControls\angularControls\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:35
>
> throw new Error("Module '" + loader.path + "' is not a loader (must have           normal or pitch function)");
>
> ^ Error: Module 
>   'D:\project\angularControls\angularControls\node_modules\url\url.js'
>
> is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)

not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has come a long way in terms of flexibility and power. Though i had the same question some time back, didn't take much time to setup a module to use bootstrap with webpack. Feel free to visit the code in [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap).

Hope it helps someone.